# Introduction to Univariate Regression and Sum of Squared Errors

Tags: probability-or-statistics

On google I find that you can manipulate a linear regression on mathemtica. If you search "Introduction to Univariate Regression and Sum of Squared Errors, Mathematica" you'll see what I'm talking about, unfortunately there is no code . I just started using mathematica and I wanted to know if anyone could show me how to do this kind of results. Thank a lot for the futur help.

Comment: That's a pretty vague and open ended question ... Have you looked here: https://reference.wolfram.com/search/?q=univariate%20regression ?

Comment: If you are talking about [this Demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/IntroductionToUnivariateRegressionAndSumOfSquaredErrors/), the code can be found from the "Source" button below the preview image.